# How can I make a button invisible if and only if its activity intented from another activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I want to make a button in an activity disabled if it is intented from a certain button and otherwise enabled if and it is intented from some other class.What I am saying will be clear after reading the code.

This is the function to intent the class containing the button.

```
showperson.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                falses=true;
                ob.truth=false;
                Toast.makeText(home_page.this, "doneit"+ob.truth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                Button clik=fb.getButton();
//                clik.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 Intent to=new Intent(home_page.this,Form.class);
                to.putExtra("buttonclik",false);
                startActivity(to);


            }
        });
```

Comment: in next activity while setting the onClick of the button check the intent and disable it if need what is question here?

Comment: No it is not clear after reading this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in `onCreate()`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null) {
    boolean isButtonClicked = intent.getBooleanExtra("buttonclik", false);
    if (isButtonClicked) {
        showperson.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

And change `false` to `true` at `to.putExtra("buttonclik",false);`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by setting a flag from the caller activity. Refer to the example below.

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityThatContainsTheButton.class);
        intent.putExtra("activity", "activityA");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityThatContainsTheButton.class);
        intent.putExtra("activity", "activityB");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public class ActivityThatContainsTheButton extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_x);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        String from = getIntent().getStringExtra("activity");
        if (from != null) {
            if (from.equals("activityA")) {
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (from.equals("activityB")) {
                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```